# Can't bind since it isn't a known property of angular component

Tags: css, angular, components

I am trying to conditionally set a classname based on a boolean variable. I have set the variable within the parent component:

```
  public alteredSidebar: boolean;
```

And this is my though process behind conditionally defining which class it is:

```
  <div [class]="alteredSidebar == false ? 'secondsidenav' : 'sidenav'" id="rollup-sidenav" [ngClass]="{ 'greyout': greyOut }"></div>
```

I have defined 2 classes with css file, one called secondsidenav and another called sidenav. Wherever I set the boolean as false, I would like the classname to equal the secondsidenav and where it is not false it be sidenav. Here is an instance of where I am using it and I am expecting the class to be set to 'secondsidenav':

```
<app-rollup [data]="rollupData" (resetCalled)="onRollupReset()" (entrySelected)="onRollupSelectEvent($event)" [alteredSidebar]="false">
            </app-rollup>
```

However I am getting the following error: "Can't bind to 'alteredSidebar' since it isn't a known property of 'app-rollup'."

Answer (score 0):

use `@Input()` decorator on it

```
@Input()
public alteredSidebar: boolean;
```

Comment: Can u provide a bit more code about your question ?

Answer (score 0):

As @junk said, you should use the @Input() decorator in the app-rollup component and I'd like to add, do not mix [className] with ngClass, this might not be related to your problem but it gets really buggy if you're using a reactive property to programatically add or remove a class, just pick one and try not to mix them it will also make the code more consistent. Oh, and the correct syntax is [className] you're probably confusing it with [class.foo]="expresion" which will apply the 'foo' class if the expression is true

Personally I'd do something like this, also sticking with one approach is [considered a best practice](https://toddmotto.com/ng-class-angular-classes#mixing-class-and-ngclass)

```
<div id="rollup-sidenav" [ngClass]="{
  'greyout': greyOut, 
  'secondsidenav': !alteredSidebar,
  'sidenav': alteredSidebar 
  }">
</div>
```

Hope that helps, let me know if it doesn't!

Answer (score 0):

@Berheet.. try this

assign the value `alteredSidebar` in the component itself and pass it like below

**parentComponent.ts**

```
public alteredSidebar: boolean = false;
```

**parentComponent.html**

```
<app-rollup [data]="rollupData" (resetCalled)="onRollupReset()" (entrySelected)="onRollupSelectEvent($event)" [alteredSidebar]="alteredSidebar">
            </app-rollup>
```

> Add Input in child component

**childComponent.ts**

```
@Input() alteredSidebar: boolean;
```

**childComponent.html**

```
<div [class]="alteredSidebar == false ? 'secondsidenav' : 'sidenav'" id="rollup-sidenav" [ngClass]="{ 'greyout': greyOut }"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I'd suggest to simply set the div-tags class property conditionally as follows

```
[class]="alteredSidebar ? 'sidenav' : 'secondsidenav'"
```

This way you get a more readable condition ? positive case : negative case flow and you don't need to compare your variable to anything.